# gethostbyaddr looping true list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the following code working

```
    import socket
    #import dns.resolver
    
    #my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    #my_resolver.nameservers = ['192.168.1.2']
    
    ip_list = []
    
    for ip in range(1, 256):
        ip_list.append('192.168.1.' + str(ip))
    
    with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
        for ip in ip_list:
            name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
            print(name)
```

my problem is that at the moment the ip has no registration in the DNS it gives an error

```
  File "/data/opt/python/resolv.py", line 15, in <module>
    name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

How can I solve this
I'm using python2 due to some limitations

Thanks in regards.

Comment: Catch the exception?

Answer (score 0):

the error ecours because there is the ip address you tried does not exists.

you can try catch the with `try and except`, or check if they are up.

`try and except`:
import socket
#import dns.resolver

```
#my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
#my_resolver.nameservers = ['192.168.1.2']

ip_list = []

for ip in range(1, 256):
    ip_list.append('192.168.1.' + str(ip))

with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    for ip in ip_list:
        try:
            name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
            print(name)
        except:
            continue
```

check if up:
import socket
#import dns.resolver

```
#my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
#my_resolver.nameservers = ['192.168.1.2']

ip_list = []

for ip in range(1, 256):
    ip_list.append('192.168.1.' + str(ip))

HOST_UP  = True if os.system("ping -c 5 " + SOMEHOST.strip(";")) is 0 else False

with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    for ip in HOST_UP:
        try:
            name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
            print(name)
        except:
            continue
```